# How to read only new changes from a file using kafka producer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, kafka-producer-api, flink-streaming

I am currently using windows machine and able to read whole file through command prompt using Kafka producer and consumer. I need to only get the recent changes in a file and need to use it in as input for Apache flink. I tried using [this link](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_kafkastreams) but due to kafka client jar mismatch issue, i was not able to use it.

In my current approach when i call my producer each time it loads the whole file and we need to run it every time to see the changes occurred to file. I thought of using threads and some way of comparing difference in file using java code but is there any of doing only by Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem recently (but in Linux) and solved it following way:

```
tail -f somefile.log | kafka-console-producer.sh ...
```

In your case you can try some Windows alternatives to Linux's tail: [13 Ways to Tail a Log File on Windows & Linux](https://stackify.com/13-ways-to-tail-a-log-file-on-windows-unix/)